# regex number range issue, can't stop -

Tags: regex

Hi I am using this to generate ranges on a switch: http://code.google.com/p/klish/wiki/subcommands

I have set the pattern to be 0-255. This works fine

```
<PTYPE name="MAX_LEARN_ADDR"
            method="integer"
            pattern="0..255"
            />
```

This correctly only accepts 0-255 and stops things like * $ £ saying they are invalid. However - causes an error. I tried:

```
 ^([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

Same thing happens.

sample legal input:

```
switch(config-if)# switchport port-security maximum 3                           
%INFO: port-security maximum is 3, up to 3 DYNAMIC addresses will be learned
```

Sample illegal input:

```
switch(config-if)# switchport port-security maximum *                           
Syntax error: Illegal parameter
```

However:

```
switch(config-if)# switchport port-security maximum -
```

gives a python trace because the - is not being caught as an invalid parameter and is getting passed to the function.

Comment: That's because `-` is not a number. Update your question with some samples of valid and invalid input.

Comment: What do you mean "causes an error"?

Comment: valid input 0, 1 ,2 up to 255. Invalid input * $ - etc. So all invalid input is being filtered out apart from -

Comment: causes an error means a python trace is being shown in the console because - is getting passed to a function expecting a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that there is an issue in klish if the range starts with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using this instead for the pattern you are supposed to allow?

**Edit 2** Alright, this should do the trick!

```
^(25[0-5]|[2][0-4]\d|[1]\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)$
```

Comment: @NaveedS What do you think now?

Comment: @inerke 206, 207 and 208 are satisfied AFAIK!

Comment: `^(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)$` (shorter) You don't need to use range for a single number. Anyway, this is working.

Answer (score 0):

`^([1-9]?\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$` would be what you need

Comment: Does the same thing, mustn't be  a problem with the regular expressions. They all filter out every invalid character except -

Comment: @Paul this regex will not allow `-`

Comment: None of the regexes I have tried should allow - so the problem is not with the regex, it must be with klish.

Comment: @Paul you checked with a valid number?your input is a string, right? shouldn't you parse it to number?

Answer (score 0):

this regex might do the work for you.

```
^25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d$
```

The first part: `25[0-5]` allows numbers between 250 to 255
The second part: `2[0-4]\d` allows numbers between 200 to 249
The third part: `1\d\d` allows numbers from 100 to 199
and the last part: `[1-9]?\d` allows numbers from 0 to 99, and makes sure that 00 or 01 do not get accepted, but 0, 1, etc do.

Comment: And please don't use useless capturing groups.

Comment: @Naveed S: Updated. Thanks for identification.